# Techniques for solving Diophantine equations.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, book-recommendation

I would like to learn new techniques for solving diophantine equations. I know how to solve diophantine equations with factorization over $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z[i]$, modular arithmetic, the Liftng The Exponent lemma and other elementary techniques, but I would like to see some more advanced techniques.

To be particular, I am interested in solving Diophantine equations by using results from Algebraic Number Theory and Algebraic Geometry.

I had a few lessons in Algebraic Number Theory and Alebraic Geometry. What topics from each of the pre-mentioned subjects would you recommend to emphasize on, if one wants to strengthen his/her Diophantine equation-solving skills?

I would also appreciate any book recommendations.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: In books usually write the classics. There are new methods not described. Although probably better to say what the equation of interest?

Comment: http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/2006/06CohenLectures.pdf